# Can we use get instead of function in swift?

Tags: swift

I have created `getName1` & `getName2()` as below

```
var myName = "Jhon"
var salt = " Salt"

    
var getName1:String {
    get {
        return myName + salt
    }
}

func getName2() ->String {
    return myName + salt
}

print("getName1\(getName1)")
print("getName2\(getName2())")
```

So instead of `getName2()` can I use `getName1` directly does that make any difference ?

Comment: For a computed read-only property you can omit the get, and in this case you can omit the return too, like this: var fullName: String { myName + salt }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference but `getName1` is a computed property while `getName2` is a function , in this case you better use `getName1` as a function is expected to do some block code or IMO not just a one line